# Dynamic database Classes

Tags: c#, .net, class, mongodb-.net-driver

I've a requirement where I need to connect my application to `2 or more databases` based on `sub-domain`.

So, I've managed to mention `multiple configurations` in `web.config` and based on that, I can connect to `multiple databases`.

Now, My problem is I've some `tables` with `different classes`.

Let's consider a table `USERS_DATA` where I've some `extra columns` for one `sub-domain`.So, I couldn't get the thought if this is possible.

I'm thinking of `dynamic loading of a class file`, but couldn't do it because we `can't define two classes with same name`.

Can someone help me, if I can achieve this requirement?

Comment: If the data modeling is different, and the business classes are different, it seems like there's little justification for these sub-domains to even be the same application in the first place.  Why not just have them be different applications, each of which can be simple and supportable and does exactly what is needed for that sub-domain?

Comment: actually the both applications have the same functionality. So, If I have a bug in one application, then we need to fix it in both the applications. so that's the reason, I'm planning to have dynamic class files. As, I'm using MongoDB, there would be a lot of unnecessary fields for every sub-domain :(